# One Weird Trick All Spammers Hate

Tags: discussion, spam

Puzzling.SE hasn't really seen much spam in the past, but we've had just a bit of it recently. Since it hasn't come up before, the question of what to do about it hasn't come up either.

Using This One Weird Trick All Spammers Hate, we can effectively quell spam that could (read: will) come up in the future. **Using spam flags on spam is critically important.**

Stack Exchange has internal systems designed to minimize and mitigate the presence of spam across the network. Posts flagged as spam carry both immediate and long-term results for spam handling. **Please don't vote to close or delete blatant spam,** as these things hide spam from being flagged down rather than resulting in its removal.

This has been a reminder sponsored by A Variety of Probably Unsafe Pills, Inc. Let me know if you all have questions!

Comment: +1 for second-to-last sentence

Comment: I'm working *so hard* to resist the urge to inappropriately flag this post as spam.

Comment: This isn't a question.. It's an answer. You're breaking the format of the site!!!!